# ValidationError: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template

Tags: terraform, launch-template

I am migrating my Autoscaling groups to use launch_template instead of launch_configuration. The plan was successful but getting the below error during terraform apply

ERROR:

```
Error: creating Auto Scaling Group (sandbox): ValidationError: You must use a valid fully-formed launch template. The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet

│ status code: 400, request id: a34faaa6-9297-4b69-81d4-3c83d57c5097

│

│ with module.app-stack.module.stack-asg.aws_autoscaling_group.asg,

│ on .terraform/modules/app-stack.stack-asg/main.tf line 70, in resource “aws_autoscaling_group” “asg”:

│ 70: resource “aws_autoscaling_group” “asg” {
```

New Code:

```
resource “aws_launch_template” “lt” {
name_prefix = “${var.name}-lt”
image_id = var.image_id
instance_type = var.instance_type
ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized
vpc_security_group_ids = var.security_groups
user_data = var.user_data
key_name = var.key_name

iam_instance_profile {
name = var.iam_instance_profile
}
block_device_mappings {
device_name = “/dev/xvda” # Root device
ebs {
volume_type = “gp2”
volume_size = var.root_volume_size
delete_on_termination = true
encrypted = true
}
}
block_device_mappings {
device_name = “/dev/xvdb”
ebs {
volume_type = “gp2”
volume_size = var.extra_volume_size
delete_on_termination = true
encrypted = true
}
}
metadata_options {
http_tokens = “required”
}
}

resource “aws_autoscaling_group” “asg” {
depends_on = [aws_launch_template.lt]
name = “${var.name}-asg”
min_size = var.asg_min
max_size = var.asg_max
desired_capacity = var.asg_desired
default_cooldown = 10
launch_template {
id = aws_launch_template.lt.id
}
vpc_zone_identifier = var.vpc_zone_identifier
target_group_arns = [var.target_group_arn]
load_balancers = [var.load_balancer]
suspended_processes = var.asg_suspended_processes

dynamic “tag” {
for_each = { for idx, val in var.tags : idx => val }
content {
key = tag.value.key
value = tag.value.value
propagate_at_launch = true
}
}

lifecycle {
create_before_destroy = true
}
}
```

Old Code:

```
resource “aws_launch_configuration” “lc” {
name_prefix = “${var.name}-lc”
image_id = var.image_id
instance_type = var.instance_type
ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized
iam_instance_profile = var.iam_instance_profile
security_groups = var.security_groups
user_data = var.user_data
key_name = var.key_name
metadata_options {
http_tokens = “required”
}
lifecycle {
create_before_destroy = true
}
root_block_device {
volume_type = “gp2”
volume_size = var.root_volume_size
encrypted = true
}
ebs_block_device {
device_name = “/dev/xvdb”
volume_type = “gp2”
volume_size = var.extra_volume_size
delete_on_termination = true
encrypted = true
}
}

resource “aws_autoscaling_group” “asg” {

name = “${var.name}-asg”
min_size = var.asg_min
max_size = var.asg_max
desired_capacity = var.asg_desired
default_cooldown = 10
launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.lc.name
vpc_zone_identifier = var.vpc_zone_identifier
target_group_arns = [var.target_group_arn]
load_balancers = [var.load_balancer]
suspended_processes = var.asg_suspended_processes
dynamic “tag” {
for_each = { for idx, val in var.tags : idx => val }
content {
key = tag.value.key
value = tag.value.value
propagate_at_launch = true
}
}
lifecycle {
create_before_destroy = true
}
}
```

I am migrating my Autoscaling groups to use launch_template instead of launch_configuration. The plan was successful but getting the below error during terraform apply

Comment: Where exactly do you use `parameter groupName`? Your code does not have any ` `groupName`.

Comment: Hey this got fixed when i completely destroyed the stack and reapplied.